# Firebird 1.5. Триггер на RDB$TRIGGERS

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Есть необходимость на сервере разработки отслеживать вызовы всех `ALTER TRIGGER`

На версии 1.0 это легко делалось навешиванием триггера `BEFORE UPDATE` на таблицу `RDB$TRIGGERS`

Проблема в том, что на версии 1.5 после разрыва соединения и переподключения такие триггера перестают работать.

Убрал все что можно, оставил вместо тела только вызов исключения - оно не возбуждается.

Выполнен на новой БД скрипт1:

```
SET TERM ^;

CREATE EXCEPTION MY_EXCEPTION ''^

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER ALTER_TRIGGER FOR RDB$TRIGGERS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (COALESCE(NEW.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG, 0) > 0) THEN EXIT;
  IF (NEW.RDB$TRIGGER_NAME = 'ALTER_TRIGGER') THEN EXIT;

  EXCEPTION MY_EXCEPTION 'NO PERMISSINO FOR CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER';
END^

COMMIT^

CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  VAL VARCHAR(10)
)^
```

После этого разрываю соединение, переподключаюсь и вызываю скрипт 2:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER FOR MY_TABLE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
    EXCEPTION MY_EXCEPTION 'Не указан ID';
END
```

Судя по тому, что второй скрипт успешно накатывается без возбуждения исключения - триггер ALTER_TRIGER не вызывается.

Как можно заставить эту схему работать?

PS Я знаю, что в 3.0 появились DDL-триггеры, но это легаси проект, растиражированный более чем на сотне точек, переход на новую версию на данный момент невозможен.

PPS Аналогичные триггеры на `RDB$PROCEDURES` работают без нареканий.

Comment: Если проект очень легаси, тогда зачем переходить на полуторку с однёрки? А уж если переходить, так почему не сразу на трёшку?

Comment: Проект был переведен с 1.0 на 1.5 порядка 10 лет назад. При этом не выполнялся beckup/restore, а просто полуторке подсунули базу от однёрки. И триггер ALTER_TRIGGER продолжал работать. Пока мне несколько дней назад не потребовалось его изменить :(